# If a and b have opposite signs then |a + b| < |a| + |b|

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Well first start with "a" positive and "-b" negative.

We have :

|a|=a

|-b|=b

|a-b|=a-b

We begin with 0 < |a| + |-b|

Then : 0 < |a| + |-b| -a

a < |a| + |-b|

a + (-b) < |a| + |-b|

which gives us : |a-b| < |a| + |-b|

We see that the result stays the same when we have -a and b.

|-a|=a

|b|=b

|b-a|=b-a

We begin with 0 < |b| + |-a|

Then : 0 < |b| + |-a| -b

b < |b| + |-a|

b + (-a) < |b| + |-a|

which gives us : |b-a| < |b| + |-a|

Thus wee see that when the signs are different the following inequality holds :

|a + b| < |a| + |b|

Is it any good ?

Comment: If $a$ is positive, and $-b$ is negative, then $a$ and $b$ are both positive (and hence do not have the same sign).

Comment: What ? I mean that the whole of it is negative (-b)=(-1)*b where b is positive

Comment: Changing the meaning of $b$ in the middle of things is not the most intelligible way to write a proof.  Plus, I don't see why $|a-b|=a-b$.  That's not going to be the case if $|b|>|a|$.

Comment: "We see that the result stays the same when we have -a and b" could have been said better. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure of understanding my error. Is it the way that I have written my message which makes it unclear at the beginning of the proof ? I'm not really sure how I was supposed to make it clear that (-b) is negative as in (-1) * b where b is postiive. How could I have written it better ?

Comment: How could I correct "|a−b|=a−b " ? Im not really sure what im supposed to do now

Comment: What you want to prove is $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$.  In the very first case, you could have started out saying "Assume $a>0$ and $b<0$," and written your inequalities with that notation, without changing the meaning of the symbols $a$ and $b$.  That way the conclusion you reach is $|a+b|<|a|+|b|$ rather than something involving $|a-b|$ which then has to be matched up with your original goal.  As for correcting $|a-b|=a-b$, if $a$ and $b$ are both positive, then if $a>b$ what you've written is correct, whereas if $a<b$ then $|a-b|=b-a$.

Comment: Ok, so I'm going to try the proof without changing the symbols. I guess this wil make things easier. I asumme that there is two cases, one where a>0 and b<0 and the other with a<0 and b>0 right ?

Comment: You can do it that way for sure.  An alternative suggestion is to divide it up into two cases $|a|<|b|$ and $|a|\ge|b|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with we must have both $a$ and $b$ nonzero, because if one of them is zero, then $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$.

1) Suppose $|a|<|b|$. Then, because $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, $a+b$ is closer to zero than $b$.  We thus have $|a+b|<|b|<|a|+|b|$.

2) Suppose $|a|=|b|$; then, because $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, $a+b=0$, and $|a+b|=0<|a|+|b|$.

3) Finally, suppose $|a|>|b|$.  Then, because $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, $a+b$ is closer to zero than $a$.  We thus have $|a+b|<|a|<|a|+|b|$.

Comment: Why the "|b|" two times ? You lost me...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I get what you mean by "the |b| two times."

Comment: Oh forget it, it's my mind playing tricks on me. Could  you justify "<|a|+|b|" I mean, I understand why it would be superior to absolute value of b but is there a more formal of showing this  or arriving at this ? Or it's ok if I just add it this way by explaining why I did this ?

Comment: I started out noting that both $a$ and $b$ have to be nonzero.  Then, $|a|>0$, and so $|b|<|a|+|b|$.  (That's because for all reals $r$ and $s$, if $s>0$ then $r<r+s$ -- very basic fact about reals.)

Comment: Oh ok, it makes sense. Last question, it seems that you imply there are three cases to prove to obtain the same result from, one where (a)>(b), one where (a)=(b) and the other where (b)>(a) Did I correctly understood you here ?

Comment: I split it up into three cases as I did so as to be able to use the intuitive notion of "closer to zero," and the fact that $|a|$ is the distance from $a$ to $0$.  This is just my weakness for reasoning geometrically -- people educated several decades ago first learned how to prove things in geometry class.  The cases I used are $|a|<|b|$, $|a|=|b|$, and $|a|>|b|$.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for the help ! Im kinda sad that I put a lot of time in my thing and it didn't work out :(

Comment: Hey I just noticed something. While your proof is correct, using "closer to zero" causes problems. b can be closer to zero than a+b. For exam, b=5 a=-99 Thus b is closer to 0 than a+b.

Comment: That is the reason for the cases.  $b=5$, $a=-99$ falls in the third case, $|a|>|b|$.  In that third case, I *don't* say that $a+b$ is closer to zero than $b$; instead, I say that $a+b$ is closer to zero than $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b>0$ and $a<0$. The other case holds by symmetry. Then if $a+b>0$ the inequality reads $a+b<b-a$ which can be rearranged to $2a<0$ which is clear. If $a+b<0$, it reads $-(a+b)<b-a$ which can be rearranged to $2b>0$ which is also clear. If $a=-b$, we have $0<2|b|$ which is clear since $b \neq 0$.

To give you some advice, considering the cases and using the definition of absolute value often gives an easy proof, though never the most elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it in a different way-

If $a$ is positive and $b$ is negative, $b<a+b<a$ and so,$|a+b|$ is less than $|a|$ or $|b|$

$|a+b| < |a|$ or  $|b|< |a|+|b|$

Comment: You need to be more preciese with the proof itself